# Can IIS 8 Request Filtering inspect/filter form posts?

Tags: iis-8, request-filtering

I have a server which is constantly being attacked by malicious scripts (from various geo-locations, so IP filtering isnt effective)

Fortunately, I have determined some of the form post values which are common and am hoping to filter the requests from my IIS 8.0 server.

Request Filtering seems to be the way forward, but so far as I can see it only applies to query string and URL.

Am I mistaken? Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks!

Comment: POST data are not inspected by IIS. You have to do it at application layer, or write your own IIS module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per comment from Lex Li:

> POST data are not inspected by IIS. You have to do it at application layer, or write your own IIS module.